# How to use OpenType fonts with plain-LuaTeX?

Tags: fonts, luatex, plain-tex, opentype

Is it possible to have OpenType fonts with LuaTeX using the plain format?

I have tried:

```
\font\test="texgyrepagellaregular"\test test\bye
```

but I get `! Font \test=texgyrepagellaregular not loadable: metric data not found or bad.`.

`mtxrun --script fonts --list --all --pattern=pagella` shows the above font name when I followed the instructions at http://wiki.contextgarden.net/Fonts_in_LuaTeX.

But on actually using the fonts, the page switches to speaking of ConTeXt instead of LuaTeX, which leaves me to wonder if it is possible to use OT-fonts with plain?

### UPDATE

Even though this now works fine for fonts which are located in my home directory (OSX Lion, BasicTeX2012, `luatex-plain`-format constructed as instructed below), I am unable to use fonts which are located in the system directories. So while the above example works (with `texgyrepagellaregular`), as the `mtxrun`-script shows its location as `~/Library/Fonts`, the following doesn't:

```
\font\test="minionproregular"
```

presumably because `mtxrun` shows its location as `/Library/Fonts` (the same issue seems to be with fonts inside `/System/Library/Fonts`).

Now, I added to my `~/.zshrc`:

```
export OSFONTDIR=/System/Library/Fonts:/Library/Fonts:$OSFONTDIR
```

after which I was able to update the fonts database with `mtxrun --script fonts --reload` (following [these instructions](http://wiki.contextgarden.net/Fonts_in_LuaTeX)), and indeed now the `mtxrun` listing does show all of the fonts.  It's just that `luatex-plain` doesn't see them.

How can I make `luatex-plain` see the fonts `mtxrun` sees?

Comment: ``mtxrun --script fonts --reload --simple`` (luatex-fonts uses its own, very simplistic font names database).

Comment: @phg: Awesome, that worked. Thank you very much! :)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Let me add to the confusion a bit:
there are actually two formats for running Plain with LuaTeX!
One of them is the format that gets called when you run the command
`luatex` from e.g. TeX Live;
egreg already posted instructions for it in
[his answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/105872/14066).

There exists, however, another format called *luatex-plain*.
Since it comes with the font loader built in, it has the advantage of
being able to use OpenType fonts without additional packages.
Here’s a demo (you’ll need the free Minion Pro fonts from Adobe for the
second part):

```
\font\iwonaregular   =file:Iwona-Regular    at 12pt
\font\iwonaitalic    =file:Iwona-Italic     at 12pt
\font\iwonabold      =file:Iwona-Bold       at 12pt
\font\iwonabolditalic=file:Iwona-BoldItalic at 12pt

{\iwonaregular     foo}\par
{\iwonaitalic      bar}\par
{\iwonabold        baz}\par
{\iwonabolditalic  xyzzy}\par

\font\minionproliningfigures =file:MinionPro_Regular         at 12pt
\font\minionprotextfigures   =file:MinionPro_Regular:+onum;  at 12pt
\font\minionprosmallcaps     =file:MinionPro_Regular:+smcp;  at 12pt

{\minionproliningfigures  0123456789abcdef}\par
{\minionprotextfigures    0123456789abcdef}\par
{\minionprosmallcaps      0123456789abcdef}\par %% implicit +onum!

\bye
```

[image: font definition demo]

For more complicated examples see
[the test file](http://repo.or.cz/w/context.git/blob/refs/heads/origin:/tex/generic/context/luatex/luatex-test.tex).

*luatex-plain* is distributed with ConTeXt and available through TeX
Live in the directory `texmf-dist/tex/generic/context/luatex/`.
(*Pro Tip*: build the format and then symlink the `luatex` binary
to `luatex-plain`, so you don’t have to specify the `--fmt`
parameter.)

Comment: This is really nice to know, Thank you very much! If I'm reading this right, it also includes the `mplib` which then has everything I could hope for. Could you include what needs to be done to build the format and symlink?

Comment: @morbusg Do you have Context installed or just TL?

Comment: Yes, I have ConTeXt installed.

Comment: 1. cd to ``$CONTEXTDIR/tex/texmf-context/tex/generic/context/luatex`` and issue ``luatex --ini ./luatex-plain.tex``; 2. copy ``luatex-plain.fmt`` to ``$CONTEXTDIR/tex/texmf-linux-64/web2c/luatex/`` (substitute your OS; also you may have to create that dir); 3. run ``$CONTEXTDIR/tex/texmf-linux-64/bin/mktexlsr``; 4. ``ln -s `which luatex` ~/bin/luatex-plain``; 5. ready!

Answer (score 20):

LuaTeX has the same font support as pdfTeX, natively. However, using the right Lua code one can extend the font support, which is precisely the job of `luaotfload.lua`. The `luaotfload.sty` file can be loaded also with the Plain LuaTeX format.

Try compiling the following file with `luatex` (note that "Linux Libertine O" is in my system fonts, I used it just by way of example.

```
\input luaotfload.sty
\font\x="texgyrepagella-regular.otf"

\font\liber="Linux Libertine O/I=5:+smcp" at 12pt

\x

abcdef

\liber

abcdef

\bye
```

[image]