# luatex cannot find font metric data

Tags: fonts, xetex, luatex, texlive, opentype

After installing TeX Live 2012 in a non system directory (not sure if this makes a difference) and running some of the tests found at [TeX Live Install](http://www.tug.org/texlive/doc/texlive-en/texlive-en.html#installation), LuaTeX can't find the example font metrics even though xetex can.

```
$ luatex opentype-info.tex 
This is LuaTeX, Version beta-0.70.2-2012062812 (TeX Live 2012)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
(./opentype-info.tex
! Font \testfont=Latin Modern Roman/ICU at 12pt not loadable: metric data not found or bad.
<to be read again> 
                   \par 
l.27 

? X
No pages of output.
Transcript written on opentype-info.log.
$ xetex opentype-info.tex 
This is XeTeX, Version 3.1415926-2.4-0.9998 (TeX Live 2012)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
(./opentype-info.tex [1] )
Output written on opentype-info.pdf (1 page).
Transcript written on opentype-info.log.
$
```

How can I fix my LuaTeX install?

Comment: You have at least to `\input luaotfload.sty`, but then the compilation fails at `\XeTeXOTcountscripts`

Comment: Related/duplicate: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/105869/how-to-use-opentype-fonts-with-plain-luatex

Comment: So this means the [Testing the Installation](http://www.tug.org/texlive/doc/texlive-en/texlive-en.html#x1-390003.5) comment `(Or the same for luatex.)` is wrong or is there additional post-install configuration that is necessary?

Comment: `opentype-info.tex` is a XeTeX specific file, so the errors are expected. The documentation is at fault here.

Comment: Thanks!  Maybe an answer should point out the fault (or ambiguity) of the TeX Live 2012 post-install tests and perhaps suggest another file to use for LuaTeX tests.  It's disconcerting for newbies when post-install tests fail.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The Web page you refer ([Testing the installation](http://www.tug.org/texlive/doc/texlive-en/texlive-en.html#x1-390003.5)) is indeed not very informative about LuaTeX.

It's not really possible to test fonts with `opentype-info.tex` by two reasons:

1. the file doesn't enable the font loading mechanism for LuaTeX;
2. it has specific XeTeX commands that LuaTeX can't understand.

A small test file might be

```
\def\myfontname{Latin Modern Roman} % <- change here

\input luaotfload.sty

\font\testfont="\myfontname" at 12pt
\testfont

Some text: the quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog

\bye
```

Comment: @egreg  Playing with the fontsize, I also found that I needed to add `\testfont` before the text.  I wonder what the default font is.

Comment: @rickhg12hs by default luatex loads the same Computer Modern fonts as pdftex (tfm, not otf).

Comment: @rickhg12hs You're again right