# How can I use times fonts in Plain TeX?

Tags: fonts, plain-tex

I'd like to use Times fonts in Plain TeX. What would be the Plain-TeX equivalent of the LaTeX command `\renewcommand{\rmdefault}{ptm}`?

Comment: If you can use XeTeX, `\font\times="Times" \times` (or `Times New Roman`) or with [LuaTeX](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/105869/how-to-use-opentype-fonts-with-plain-luatex).

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Looking at `mathptmx.sty`, the following should do

```
\font\tenrm=ptmr7t at 10pt % roman text
\font\sevenrm=ptmr7t at 7pt
\font\fiverm=ptmr7t at 5pt

\font\tenbf=ptmb7t at 10pt % boldface extended
\font\sevenbf=ptmb7t at 7pt
\font\fivebf=ptmb7t at 5pt

\font\tensl=ptmro7t at 10pt % slanted roman

\font\tenit=ptmri7t at 10pt % text italic

% for math family 0 we need a font different from ptmr7t    
\font\tenrmop=zptmcm7t at 10pt
\font\sevenrmop=zptmcm7t at 7pt
\font\fivermop=zptmcm7t at 5pt

\textfont0=\tenrmop
\scriptfont0=\sevenrmop
\scriptscriptfont0=\fivermop

\font\teni=zptmcm7m at 10pt % math italic
\font\seveni=zptmcm7m at 7pt
\font\fivei=zptmcm7m at 5pt

\font\tensy=zptmcm7y at 10pt % math symbols
\font\sevensy=zptmcm7y at 7pt
\font\fivesy=zptmcm7y at 5pt

\font\tenex=zptmcm7v at 10pt % math extension

\tenrm % choose default
```

Comment: OK. However \font\tensl=ptmbo7t at 10pt should be substituded with

Comment: \font\tensl=ptmro7t at 10pt otherwise you get boldface slanted.

Comment: @Luigi Sorry for the typo.

Answer (score 5):

If you use `opmac` (distributed with csplain), simply type `\input ctimes`. In that case the `tx-math.tex` is loaded, which activates the TX fonts for math. If you need the T1 encoded fonts, type `\input t1code` before `\input ctimes`. You can change all sizes of the loaded fonts simply by stating, for example, `\typosize[11.5pt/13.5pt]`. If you use `xetex` or `luatex` then you can type `\input ucode \input cs-termes` to load the unicoded variant Termes from TeXGyre. Make sure you have all the required fonts, csfonts in particular, installed.

Comment: of the files you recommend, none seem to be in a normal plain-tex environment -- the ones i've located are in csplain (plain tex for czechs & slovaks, or something).  whatever, they seem not to be present in my installation.  are you suggesting that non-slavic people don't use plain tex?

Comment: @wasteofspace There is only plain.tex and hyphen.tex in normal plain-tex environment. It is our decision to choose only this starting point and nothing more. But if users want to use some additional macros for plain TeX, they can use eplain or csplain. These packages are comparable. The csplain serves multilanguage support today. It is signed as "for czech and slovak" only from historical reason.

Comment: @wasteofspace I can say that csplain is most definitely NOT just for Czech/Slovak.  I have used it with great success the past few weeks now.  All the TeXGyre fonts are available out of the box with commands like `\input cs-bonum` or `\input cs-termes`.  I highly recommend this TUGboat article: https://www.tug.org/TUGboat/tb34-1/tb106olsak-csplain.pdf.  Also, If you use the OPmac package you get even more font conveniences.  I haven't used csplain with pdftex or xetex much, mostly just luatex.  csplain is a format so its best to invoke with something like: `luatex --fmt=pdfcsplain ...`

Answer (score 1):

If you want to load times fonts for text, you may use the [plnfss](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/plnfss) package for plain.

```
\input plnfss
\usefont{LY1}{ptm}{m}{n}
```

beware you will switch to the LY1 encoding (LY1 is a superset of Latin1, roughly equivalent to win1252). You may need to install [fonts encoded that way](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/ly1).

plnfss also provides with the classic LaTeX calls to switch attributes (\textit, \textbf, etc), but is limited in switching sizes.