# How to compile a plain LuaTeX file

Tags: luatex

How do I write and compile a `.tex` file with plain `LuaTeX`? I use `LuaLaTeX` to compile some `.tex` files but how is an example of a plain `LuaTeX` file and how do I compile it? In the [reference manual](http://www.pragma-ade.com/general/manuals/luatex.pdf) I did not find any example or a tutorial of how to do it. Is there any resource material in which I can learn more about creating and compile `.tex` files with plain `LuaTeX`?

Comment: I don't think there's anything special between plain LuaTeX vs. LuaLaTeX files as compared to how plain TeX vs. LaTeX files differ. You just write a plain TeX file in which you can use the new LuaTeX primitves, and compile that file via `luatex myfile.tex`.

Answer (score 1):

It's important to understand than Plain TeX is only defined for TeX although it can be seen as a model to build more advanced TeX engines. Strictly speaking, there is no Plain TeX format for LuaTeX but a [plain LuaTeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/105892/166576).

The idea is to define its own format like e.g. [OpTeX](https://ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/luatex/optex) or define a format "from scratch" using the engine primitives.

**Note:** In practice `luatex-plain.tex` actually reads `plain.tex` but it also reads `luatex-basics`, `luatex-fonts`, `luatex-math`....